# How to make my laser cutter follow my paths in a logical order?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, laser-cutting

I have a Trotec Speedy 300 and when I print some shapes imported from a DXF into Illustrator (lines are joined, red and thickness is 0.0001 mm), the laser cutter is printing one segment then it jumps at another location and print another segment. Eventually the cutting efficiency is pretty bad.

Why is the laser cutter not doing a continous cut and how to fix this?

Here a visual example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX6ZtOGIWKA

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with laser cutting, but I would believe that the cutter cuts in the order the paths are layered. Maybe you can check that in the "Layers panel"? How to fix it (besides manually moving paths to the right order) I have no idea.

Comment: I have one Trotec Speedy 300 laser cut machine, too. I also have the same problem as you Do you have the solution now? Can you help me?
Hope for your reply, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to solve this problem:

1. Use the "Vector Ordering" function in Trotec JobControl 11.2.1.1, it will re-orders all vectors to an optimized sequence.
2. Use third party CAD software to re-construction the dxf line sequence, such as "SolidWorks+NESTINGWorks" to export the dxf file.

[image: Laser Cut Line Sequence]

[image: Vector Ordering Manual]

[image: Vector Ordering]

Answer (score 2):

Trotec job control respects your wishes. By default JobControl cuts exactly in the order you drew the segments. This is offcourse easy in illustrator where you can just order the damn thing as you wish. But many cad applications  dont work in a way to make this obvious.

Now step one is to join your damn stuff. This makes laying out easier and enables you to use nesting tools in your design end. However i find for architectural models this is often too complex so use the second option and run an optimizer in JobControl, right click on the job and do quick optimize.

Third option is to use job coloring order.

PS: Job control can work trough the printer driver. And i find that it iss better not to use illustrator as a intermediary for cad data but rather print it directly out of your cad. Though this wont work for Fusion 360

Answer (score 1):

The software with which you control the machine determines the cutting sequence. For laser cutters with RD designated controllers, RDWorks is shipped/packaged with the device. A third party software developer has created Lightburn Software for the same controller (and many others) and often addresses similar problems related to cutting sequences. Lightburn is substantially easier when it comes to specifying cutting actions.

It is not uncommon that DXF files are composed of individual segments rather than one continuous line. If you can convert the DXF into a different, accepted format for your laser, and join the segments, you may have better luck.

You may get more assistance if you can provide the name of the software used to send your work to the laser. If you know of a forum specific to your controller (let us know your controller type) you may also find an answer there.

Comment: Trotec has its own software. And it does things by default in exactly the sequence you drew the damn thing. Good thing too. Anyway while its not as sophisticsted as LightBurn the trotecs drives are way way better except for one part of the engraving feature. The laser machine is way way better than any of the RD machines though, i know i have both at work. If the trotec is free therrs no reason to use the other even if it has morepoweron paper (the trotec is still faster and cuts with superior quality, but then its 8 times as expensive)